# How to parse inner multiple <p> tags text with each or loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I want to parse news texts which are in multiple `<p>` texts. Cant get only texts from those p tags.

Sample url : https://www.prothomalo.com/sports/article/1590573

I have found all `<p>` tags text with tag. but i want to get only texts with loop or something else. Need help to get those texts only.

My solution with `<p>` tags:

```
$('#widget_51897 > div > div > div.row.detail_holder > div.right_part > div > article > div').text()
```

Please give me solution on cheerio(NodejS)
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no p tags ?

Comment: @Nazmul Hossain, try like this `                jQuery('div [itemprop="articleBody"] > p').each(function (index, value) {
$(value).text()`

Comment: you can't use `.val()` on `<p>`, `.val()` is for inputs

Comment: Why the `scrapy` tag? This does not look like Scrapy, and you also tag as `javascript`, while Scrapy is a Python framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
const allPElements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(let {innerText} of allPElements){
  console.log(innerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to get all the p texts under `[itemprop="articleBody"]`:

```
const texts = $('[itemprop="articleBody"] p').map((i, p) => $(p).text()).get()
```